# How to update multiple columns in mysql using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

How to update the multiple columns in MySQL using node.js:

```
var query = 'UPDATE employee SET profile_name = ? WHERE id = ?';
connection.query(query,[req.name,req.id] function (error, result, rows, fields) {
```

but I have to update `profile_name`, `phone,email`, `country`, `state`, `address` at once.
How can I do that, can anyone suggest.

Comment: In case you see this: Titus posted the best answer, and it should be the accepted one.

Comment: @ChrisG Do you see the date of the question? I think the answer from today is not relevant for OP

Comment: @Jens I'm fully aware that this question was posted in 2016, it is however a perfect duplicate of a current question which I wanted to flag as such. To my knowledge SO is supposed to be a repository of useful questions and answers, and updating an older question / answer is not only acceptable but encouraged.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply add all columns in set:

```
var query = 'UPDATE employee SET profile_name = ?, phone =?, .. WHERE id=?';

connection.query(query,[req.name,req.phone,...,req.id] function (error, result, rows, fields) {
```

Comment: There's no way to do this dinamically? Something like calling an utility function passing only the column names?

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra There is: one can pass an object to `SET ?`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59960177/5734311

Comment: @Downvoter: Thanks for downvoting without explanation

Answer (score 8):

‍ **To update your multiple columns in mysql using nodejs**, then You can do it like this code below:

```js
const query = 'UPDATE `employee` SET ? WHERE ?';
connection.query(query, [req.body, req.params], function(err, rows) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    // do some stuff here
  } else {
    console.log(rows);
    // do some stuff here
  }
});
```

> **Make sure** your `req.body` is not `empty` and the field in your `req.body` it's same with the field in your `employee` table.

If your `req.body` is `undefined` or `null`, then you can add this middleware to your express server:

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

I hope it can help you .

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE` statement syntax :

```
UPDATE <TableName>
SET <Col1> = <Val1>,
    <Col2> = <Val2>,
    ....
WHERE id = ?
```