# Update data with NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to update my user data in database with node app (using expressJs) but it returns this error in terminal:

```
 sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL WHERE `id` = '1'' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "UPDATE `users` SET NULL WHERE `id` = '1'"
```

## Code

`index.js`

```
var Users = require('./routes/Users');
app.put('/users/:id/update', Users.update);
```

`Users.js`

```
'use strict';

var response = require('../res');

exports.update = function(req, res) {
    req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        connection.query('UPDATE `users` SET ? WHERE `id` = ?',  [req.body, req.params.id], function(err, rows) {
            if (err)
                console.log("%s ", err);

            response.success(rows, res);
        });
    });
};
```

`sending request`

[image: one]

> Can you tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: You need to put in the query which column you want to set, like this: `UPDATE \`users\` SET \`name_of_column\` = ? WHERE \`id\` = ?`

Comment: pretty sure ```req.body``` isn't what you're supposed to be using, the error says NULL where, so req.body is null

Comment: @ChrisG can we make it dynamic? because any column can be set for update is not something static like say only username column, it can be email column or both.

Comment: @BrianPutt i know, i just found this update function on net and changed it to my code, but not sure how exactly it suppose to be.

Comment: @ChrisG it says `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: I would modify your logic to utilize JSON as the payload and hardcode the column, so basically don't rely on user input to determine what column should be used

Comment: @BrianPutt you mean something like this? ```'UPDATE `users` SET `username`, `email`, `user_type`, `approved` WHERE `id` = ?',  [req.body, req.params.id],```

Comment: solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000360/sql-if-not-null-update

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the code below:

```js
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.params);
  req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      connection.query('UPDATE `users` SET ? WHERE ?',  [req.body, req.params], function(err, rows) {
          if (err)
              console.log("%s ", err);

          response.success(rows, res);
      });
  });
};
```

> I've been trying with the code above and it's working fine.

Make sure your `req.body` is not empty and the field in your `req.body` it's same with the field in your `users` table.

If your `req.body` is undefined or null, then you can add this middleware to your express server:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: This is the perfect answer, you should add it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484123/how-to-update-multiple-columns-in-mysql-using-nodejs

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `sql` query has a problem. Please add a column name for update.

```
sql = `UPDATE users SET column = NULL WHERE id = '1'`
```

Or You can use

```
sql = `UPDATE users SET column = ? WHERE id = ?`
con.query(sql,[id]);
```

Before that Make create the connection.

**NOTE: DON'T USE `''` for table name and column name**