# SQL if not null update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have this query

```
UPDATE users SET username = Param1,email = Param2,PASSWORD = Param3 WHERE id = Param4;
```

this is updating my user row, *but i want to say:* If email OR password **is not null** update them otherwise let them be as they are.

What should my query be like then?

## UPDATE

By friends codes below I realized now that my form sent empty string `''` and not `null` so I think I need to check if my password is not `''` and if my email is not `''` instead of if it's not null.

#### About logic

I think some misunderstood me by my question,

I'd like my values of columns `email` and `password` change if i send new values trough my form,

If i didn't fill for instance my email input in my form then my email in database doesn't need to be change (updated).

So just update each column in case their value is not empty string.

Comment: Do you really mean you want to keep NULL email and password?

Comment: *If email OR password is not null update them otherwise let them be as they are.* Maybe backward - set if NULL and stay unchanged if NOT NULL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If email OR password is not null update them otherwise let them be as they are.

You can use `case` expressions for this. I think that the logic you want is:

```
UPDATE users 
SET 
    username = Param1
    email = case when email is not null then Param2 end,
    password = case when password is not null then Param3 end
WHERE id = Param4;
```

Or if you want to update email and password if *both* are not `null` then:

```
UPDATE users 
SET 
    username = Param1
    email = case when email is not null and password is not null then Param2 end,
    password = case when email is not null and password is not null then Param3 end
WHERE id = Param4;
```

---

Now the question was updated and I understand that you want to perform the update if and only if both email and password *parameters* are not empty strings. So you actually want *filtering*. I would phrase this as:

```
UPDATE users 
SET username = Param1, email = Param2, password = Param3 
WHERE id = Param4 and Param2 <> '' and Param3 <> ''
```

Or if you want to separate the logic for both parameters:

```
UPDATE users 
SET 
    username = Param1, 
    email = case when Param2 <> '' then Param2 else email end, 
    password = case when Param3 <> '' then Param3 else password end
WHERE id = Param4;
```

Comment: your first code still empty my password in database, second one is not my intended case but it's good to know it thanks.

Comment: *"your first code still empty my password in database"* This is certainly because of the content of `Param3`

Comment: Param3 is `''` so it's null, normally should be untouched right? that's what i'm looking for, if is `''` then don't update that column

Comment: `''` is not `NULL`, it's `''` (`NULL` means no value, an empty string is a value) Check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: hmmm, then i need to check `''` instead of `null`

Comment: I think this is not good because this will always update username.

Comment: @mafortis your question needs to be updated, adding the empty string information.

Comment: thanks, i think you got me wrong again `update if and only if both email and password`,  i make it separate as much as possible for you,  `1- if email is not empty string, update email`, `2- if password is not empty string, update password`. one by one not both together,

Comment: yep i see your 4th logic now :) i try that :D

Comment: your 4th code works perfectly for me, thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

Like this

```
UPDATE users 
SET 
  username = Param1,
  email = COALESCE(Param2, email),
  password = COALESCE(Param3, password)
WHERE id = Param4;
```

COALESCE works from left to right taking the first non null argument. If you provide null as Param2, it will update email  to email (no change). If you provide a value to Param2, coalesce will return that non null value so email is updated to whatever param2 is

Ps: understood your request to be "I will provide either a null or a value in the parameter. If I provide a null I don't want to update the db table. If I provide a value I do want to update the DB table"

This seemed more logical to me than how your question reads which is "if my table value is null for email then I forever want it to remain null and never want any of the values I supply in the parameters to be written to the table"

Comment: same issue as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000360/sql-if-not-null-update#comment106111947_60000396

Comment: You need to understand the difference between null and empty string. Empty string is a value. Null is no value. Only Oracle db treats them the same. You specify null in the question ..

Comment: so i understand that by now :) how should i say empty string instead of null here? PS: i will update my question.

Comment: You can't use empty string with coalesce because it specifically works on nulls. If you use an empty string as the first argument ParamX it will always pick the first argument. If you want to use coalesce you will have to have your sproc/front end populate the parameters with NULLs

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE users 
SET username = Param1,
email = Param2,
PASSWORD = Param3 
WHERE id = Param4 AND (ISNULL(email,'') != '' OR ISNULL(PASSWORD, '') != '');
```

Comment: Why `ISNULL(email,'') != ''` when one can do `email IS NOT NULL` ?

Comment: It is for safety. If you leave "email IS NOT NULL" you are risking update if you have empty string in email field.

Comment: i cannot save your code is says `Incorrect parameter count in the cell to native function 'ISNULL'`

Comment: @Katusic this makes sense. This should be explained in your answer (However, it doesn't update the username if mail/password aren't empty, this is what OP asked for)

Comment: Indeed, replace `ISNULL` by `IFNULL`

Comment: Ok now saved but i get same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000360/sql-if-not-null-update#comment106111947_60000396

Comment: Can you be more specific or post all code here with values?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works..

```
 DECLARE @email varchar(100), @password varchar(50)
    SET @email = null  
    SET @password = null

    IF @email <= (SELECT email from users WHERE id = Param4)   
    UPDATE users SET username = Param1,email = Param2,PASSWORD = Param3 WHERE id = Param4;

    IF @password <= (SELECT PASSWORD from users WHERE id = Param4)   
    UPDATE users SET username = Param1,email = Param2,PASSWORD = Param3 WHERE id = Param4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
UPDATE users 
   SET username = Param1, email = Param2, PASSWORD = Param3 
 WHERE id = Param4
   AND CONCAT(email,password) IS NOT NULL;
```

I've tried with MySQL version 4, 5.x and 8 with MariaDB 10, whenever you do `CONCAT` on columns where one of the column value is NULL, you'll always get NULL result.

**Edit:** For empty string, something like this.

```
UPDATE users 
   SET username = Param1, email = Param2, PASSWORD = Param3 
 WHERE id = Param4
   AND CONCAT(email,password) <> '';
```

For both NULL and empty string, something like this.

```
UPDATE users 
   SET username = Param1, email = Param2, PASSWORD = Param3 
 WHERE id = Param4
   AND CONCAT(email,password) IS NOT NULL OR CONCAT(email,password) <> '';
```

Comment: thanks, would you mind check my question update part please?